# Scroll Hotmail Signup page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, imacros

Hi guys is there any way to scroll [hotmail signup page](https://signup.live.com/signup.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1417454720&rver=6.4.6456.0&wp=MBI_SSL_SHARED&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx%3Frru%3Dinbox&id=64855&cbcxt=mai&bk=1417454721&uiflavor=web&uaid=c7945c251e094f8bac3b98401e2dc507&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&lic=1) using Javascript?
I've tried `scrollBy` and `scrollTo` and nothing seems to work.

Thank you for your help!
Cheers

Comment: Can you show us how you used `scrollBy` and `scrollTo`?

Comment: window.scrollTo(0, 20000);
window.scrollBy(0, 20000);

Nothing happens, but it works on all other pages except that one.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You can't scrollTo because the scroll is not attached to the window element. 
If you look into their code you'll see a div('#c_base') with absolute positioning that 'holds' the scrollbar when it overflows.

Something like this should work:

```
var el = document.getElementById('c_base');
el.scrollTop = 300;
```

Comment: What you said is indeed an answer, and it works. Definitely not a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!!! I'm sorry I can't vote you up because you really deserved it!!!